# Undefined variable $pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to make a DB with Mysql and PHP however I am getting a error after trying to post the data
here is my error

```
Warning: Undefined variable $pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\includes\formhandler.inc.php on line 15

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\includes\formhandler.inc.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\includes\formhandler.inc.php on line 15
```

here is my formhandler.inc.php

```
<?php


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    
    try {
     require_once "dbh.inc.php";

     $query  = "INSERT INTO users (username, pwd, email) VALUES 
     (?, ?, ?);";

     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

     $stmt->execute([$username, $pwd, $email]);

     $pdo = null;
     $stmt = null;
     header ("location: ../index.php");
     die();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}else {
header ("location: ../index.php");
}
```

here is the dbh.inc.php

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myfirstdatabase";
$dbusername = "root"
$dbpassword = "root"

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $pdo-> setATTRibute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    
    //throw $th;
}
```

I was epecting it to fully post the data...

Comment: So where is `$pdo` defined?

Comment: We might expect `$pdo` is defined in `dbh.inc.php`, but we can only guess because you didn't post the code of that file.

Comment: sorry just updated..

Comment: Why do you catch a connection error? Can your script continue with a failed database connection? I'd guess not. So in that case there's no reason to catch the error. Just let it crash and php will log the exception

Comment: As you have written it, the script should echo the exception message if it fails to connect to the database. Did it echo that message? If so, why doesn't the code exit the script? It will continue on even if the PDO connection fails, and then subsequent code that relies on `$pdo` will find that variable has not been set.